# Google translate API not working in firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am struggling to figure out whether google-translate-api stopped working in firebase functions. I have the following code which used to work but now all I get is locale Not Supported.

```
exports.translateNow = functions.database.ref('/Translate/lang'.onWrite(event => {
let loc='en';//event.data.val();
console.log("LOCA "+loc);
translateMessage('Ik spreek Engels',loc).then(function(result){
     console.log("PYAM ",result);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("ERR ",err);
});
return true;});
```

The locale is read from firebase database but I've hard coded en for English which is still not working.

Here is translateMessage

```
let translateMessage=function(text,loc){
let theLoc=loc;
if(theLoc=='ab'||theLoc=='aa'||theLoc=='ak'||theLoc=='an'||theLoc=='as'||theLoc=='av'||theLoc=='ae'||theLoc=='ay'||theLoc=='bm'||theLoc=='ba'||theLoc=='bh'||theLoc=='ce'||theLoc=='zh'||theLoc=='ki'){
    theLoc='en'
}


return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    translate(text, {from: 'en', to: theLoc}).then(res => {
      resolve(res.text);
    }).catch(function(result){
          reject("Not Supported");             
    }); 

});};
```

Please someone help here's my include `const translate = require('google-translate-api');`

Comment: Why don't you use the official Google translate API instead?  https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/translate/2.1.x/

Comment: It might be useful to log the error message you get and see if it contains a hint to the problem: `.catch(function(result){ console.error(result); ...`.

Comment: The official API worked, thanks.

Comment: Note that you have to upgrade to a paid plan (even Pay As You Go) to make external web requests.